# App freezes on connection loss, no debugging tools available

Tags: c#, android, sockets, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a bit of a problem as I have developed a C# Xamarin app for Android, which is a client, and in parallel, a server in another language. They interact with each other via TCP/IP sockets.

The Android app is, broadly speaking a geo localized app. Now, because of the nature of mobile network, I have implemented a way to detect if there is a connection to the server, and if not, automatically reconnect. When an operation on a socket fails, the app is directly put in offline mode.

During this time, everything is supposed to work: the main activity is a map that follows the user.

If I make the server crash, it indeed works as expected: it tries to reconnect every time once in a while and during this time the map is "updated" (the angle changes depending on bearing, etc), a "no connection" button appears, and when the server is back online, it reconnects.

But when I have no more network or set my phone in plane mode, it freezes.

There is no exception. I've put breakpoints everywhere, to no effect. I have no idea what is going on at all. 
On top of that, it seems that the Android system itself is freezing and I have no real idea, to be honest, how android does the things my app asks it to perform, and what would cause this freeze. I mostly need to either reboot my phone or wait very long times. The bearings aren't updated, the map doesn't move like it does when the server crashes.

I have tried making my socket timeout. I've tried to use other properties of the socket to determine if it's disconnected in this way. I've put try catch blocks around every use of the socket, forcing the disconnection whenever an operation fails.

It's not really possible to show entire activities as I have multiple thousands of lines on this project. I can however show how I determine connection status, and how I connect/reconnect my socket.

How I check connection status:

```
        public bool checkConnectionStatus()
        {
            bool part1 = true;
            try
            {
                part1 = sock.Poll(1000, SelectMode.SelectRead);
            }
            catch
            {
                connected = false;
                return false;
            }
            bool part2 = (sock.Available == 0);
            if (part1 && part2)
            {
                connected = false;
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                connected = true;
                return true;
            }
        }
```

What is called to start the socket for the first time, but also whenever it's disconnected and I want it to reconnect:

```
public void socketStartup()
        {
            socketStartupLocked = true;
            ip = IPAddress.Parse(ipstring);
            ipe = new IPEndPoint(ip, port);
            try
            {
                sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, System.Net.Sockets.SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp)
                {
                };
            }
            catch
            {
                connected = false;
                socketStartupLocked = false;
                return;
            }
            try
            {
                sock.Connect(ipe);
                connected = true;
            }
            catch
            {
                connected = false;
                socketStartupLocked = false;
                return;
            }
            socketStartupLocked = false;
        }
```

I expect my app to behave when there's no network exactly as it does when the server is down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably only check the server/socket connection after checking your device network connectivity.

For reference on how to do it:

https://github.com/xamarin/docs-archive/tree/master/Recipes/android/networking/detect-network-connection

And remember to add the following permission to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: These are different things? What happens to a socket when there's no connection to it vs when the server goes down?

Comment: In the end, you seemed to be right. I added a connectivity check beforehand, and if it doesn't work, I just don't do the other check. This solved my problem and although the socket isn't recreated in this case, the app doesn't freeze anymore. I'll probably figure this other problem out as it's probably just a bad condition somewhere. Thanks a lot.